# Div with overflow-y: auto inside body - only scroll this div when mouse is over it (not body)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have something like:

`<body>...content...<div></div>...content...</body>`

And I want the div inside the body to be scrollable. I used `overflow-y:auto` and it works but when the body itself is so high that it is scrollable it does not work anymore (then the whole page is scrolled, not the div). I tried to fix it with `position:fixed` on the body but then the page is scrolled to the top.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: You may set the overflow for div only and set the `overflow:hidden;` for body

Comment: This fixes the "scrolling to top" problem of the body but I cannot scroll the div with the mousewheel anymore. And btw it only worked when I set the whole html to overflow:hidden.

Comment: [Refer this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJ4qc/167/)